# How to fix the following error java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I try to run my project, I am getting the following errors:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'transaction_isolation'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
```

I am running this project on Manjaro and I have never had this issue before. I did not update or remove anything related to Mysql or Java Springboot. Also, I tried to change the dependencies' version(I saw this in a post) but it did not work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to check the global and session values of transaction characteristics at runtime:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation;
SELECT @@SESSION.transaction_isolation;
```

The first one is to run a database query that sets the transaction isolation level for every session on the database. The query is:

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Fix it! Thnak you!